consulta por theme de wordpress
Con el gusto en saludarlos, tengo las siguientes consultas.
La primera, como se llama esta sección del menú de los themes.

La segunda, es que tengo entendido que se deben usar hook para cambiar o modificar los datos para poder hacerlo personalizable, quisiera agregar algunas funciones a un tema personalizado que estoy haciendo para algo personal.
ejemplo, agregar un ítem para cambiar el resise de un div o hacerlo personalizable por porcentaje. o personalizar el ancho de la pagina o de las entradas.
Si me pudieran dar alguna guía que fuese buena, se los agradecería mucho de antemano.

La imagen pertenece al diseñador del Theme. Es donde modificas cosas. Con lo segundo debes ser especifico, debes leer [ask] y el [tour] para que se te pueda ayudar
